How to force action "greylist" in rspamd
I want to force greylisting on all mails that have matched a public blocklist, even if they don't reach the configured score for greylisting.
The greylisting module has a setting called whitelist_symbols, but no blacklist_symbols unfortunately, so I'm trying to do that using the force_actions module.
My idea is this, local.d/force_actions.conf:
rules {
  greylist_all_spamlist_results {
    action = "greylist"

    # avoid greylisting only if it would otherwise be accepted (don't change "reject"):
    require_action = ["no action", "add header", "rewrite subject"] 

    # trigger if any blacklist symbol is matched
    expression = "RBL_SPAMHAUS_PBL or DBL_SPAM or RBL_SPAMHAUS_XBL or RBL_SPAMHAUS_SBL"
  }
}

The documentation is not very clear on this, unfortunately.

Is "greylist" even a valid action? The documentation doesn't list it, but it seems to be accepted (screenshot of the history tab in the WebUI):

This was a test mail that wasn't resubmitted, so it unfortunately doesn't answer question 2 (below).
I know the greylisting module triggeres a "soft reject" when greylisting is triggered, but that doesn't mean the action "soft reject" is a synonym of "greylist". It's just the method to reject for greylisting, so using "soft reject" here would 100% always reject the mail.

How does the action "greylist", assuming it exists, handle a mail that HAS been greylisted, resubmitted, and finally accepted?
What happens if force_actions changes the "no action" into "greylist" at that point? Will it (1) be soft rejected again, leading to a rejection loop? Will it (2) lead to a endless loop of action switching within the session, leading to a lock up? Or will it (3) simply work?
It seems like I should exclude previously greylisted mails from the rule, but I can't see any way to do that in the force_actions documentation.


